# Images in FlyoutAnchor submenu items – CRM 2011 ribbon

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

Is it possible to display images next to items in FlyoutAnchor submenu?

I try to use same attributes for the Button element in submenu as for the regular one and it doesn’t work for me.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
          <FlyoutAnchor Id="myFlyoutOtherAct"
                        ToolTipTitle="$Resources:Ribbon.HomepageGrid.Add.Related.OtherActivities" ToolTipDescription=""
                        LabelText="$Resources:Ribbon.HomepageGrid.Add.Related.OtherActivities" Alt="$Resources:Ribbon.HomepageGrid.Add.Related.OtherActivities" 
                        Sequence="80" 
                        Command="Mscrm.Enabled" 
                        Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/customactivity_16.png" Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/customactivity_32.png"                            
                        TemplateAlias="c9">
            <Menu Id="myMenuOtherAct">
              <MenuSection Id="myMenuSectOtherAct" 
                           Title="OtherActivities" 
                           Sequence="15">
                <Controls Id="myControlsOtherAct">
                  <Button Id="myButtonLetter" Command="Mscrm.CreateLetter" 
                          ToolTipTitle="{!EntityDisplayName:letter}" ToolTipDescription="" LabelText="{!EntityDisplayName:letter}" Alt="{!EntityDisplayName:letter}" 
                          **Image16by16="/_imgs/ribbon/entity16_4207.png" Image32by32="/_imgs/ribbon/entity32_4207.png"**
                          TemplateAlias="isv" Sequence="10"/>
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. You need to set the `DisplayMode` of the `MenuSection` equal to the value you want.

[MenuSection (RibbonDiffXml)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334378.aspx)

```xml
<MenuSection Id="myMenuSectOtherAct"
             Title="OtherActivities"
             Sequence="15"
             DisplayMode="Menu16">
```